# How to move Swing components from JFrame to JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jscrollpane

I have almost completed my Java application designed in Netbeans using `JFrame`. The mistake I have made is that I have put all my components directly on the frame rather than a `JPanel`. Now I want to make the frame scrollable, but I don't know how I can transfer all my components to a scroll pane from the frame. Any other way of making the frame scrollable?

Comment: `The mistake I have made is that I have put all my components directly on the jframe rather than a jpanel` - that is correct, it is a mistake. You know the solution, there is no easy way out. Add the components to a panel and add the panel to the viewport of the scroll pane. Then add the scroll pane to the frame.

Comment: Perhaps you should not have so many controls and display items on a single screen.  This is where a layout such as `CardLayout`, or a component like a `JTabbedPane` comes in handy.  What is the application and why does the main GUI require so much screen acreage?

Comment: Assuming you've done this in form editor, you can select all the components, hit [ctrl]+[x], create a new `JPanel` form, make sure the layout managers are the same, and press [ctrl]+[p] to past the content into the new form (make sure you've selected it first).  This will, at least, move the components and event handlers, but you  may still need to copy some code between the two

Comment: I have made a new JPanel form and pasted my components there. Presently copying the remaining code. so finally how do add a scroll pane.

Comment: @andrew it is a temperture simulation software that gives tankwise temperatures of cargo on a ship subject to weather conditions. The point is it has 5 JTabels, 2 combo boxes and 4 buttons. They fit nicely on a single screen, but when i resize it and make it smaller, i need a scroll bar.

Comment: *"so finally how do add a scroll pane."* create a panel (maybe called `gui`) and set it to a `new GridLayout()`.  Create a scroll-pane with your user interface as the 'component' parameter, e.g. `new JScrollPane(simulationView)`.  Add the scroll pane to the `gui` (as the only component) add the `gui` to the frame.

Comment: BTW - do the 4 different tables have 4 different groups of table column headers?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(getContentPane(),
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  this.setContentPane(pane);
```

and add a preferred size to your content pane

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
```

I got the same problem and the above code worked for me.